# Java EE multi layered architecture

Tags: jakarta-ee

We are developing a Java EE web application in JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces (presentation), EJB 3.1 (Business) and JPA (persistence).

We want to make each layer independent, so that in the future any other application that wants to access our application should be able to do so easily.

So we have a plan to expose our EJBs as web service calls.

What we found is that our presentation layer looks tightly coupled, where model and controller and view are together as a framework.

We'd like to know how we can expose the model and controller as a separate service so that any outside view can access these easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expose the controller separately in JSF. It's the Faces Servlet that's being provided by the framework.

Don't expose the model directly either. In JSF terms the entry into the model is the backing bean. This type of bean is specific to a page and should not be reused.

A backing bean should not contain business logic. Instead it merely delegates to a Service bean, which is often an EJB.

Those services and the (JPA) entities they use should be designed so that they can be reused. This can be done at a later stage via JAX-RS, JAX-WS, Remote EJB, or maybe just by copying those beans to a jar and including them in another app.

Just make sure for now that your services don't depend on any UI package and that they don't try to do any UI work. Worry about the exact way to reuse them when you have those other apps.

Comment: Thank You Mr.Braun for your reply. You are right. We were thinking to make a common model. It looks like no possible with the framework. How about using JPA for our persistence layer, when there are lot of frequent  changes in the database.